# SqlQuery return -1 in EF using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to run query in EF but when I run this query in SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT THEN return "00002" but when I run in EF, this query return -1. I don't know what is happing any senior can you tell where i am wrong.
I also share the screenshot of the query result where you can see the return result.
error: "-1".

I am sharing the C# function where I fetch the query from the database and call the function using jquery. function working properly but query result is wrong . Why? I don't know.

**C#**

```
public int Maxnumber()
        {

            int result = _db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("select RIGHT('00000' + cast(ISNULL(MAX(User_Id),0)+1 as varchar(5)) + '',6)from secUsers");

                return result;
        }




public JsonResult max_UserID()
        {
            var mNo= _IAccount.Maxnumber();
            return Json(mNo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            
          
        }
```

Jquery

```
 function MaxNo() {
          $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              url: '@Url.Action("max_UserID")',
              dataType: 'json',
              data: {},
              success: function (mNo) {

                  $("#userid").val(mNo);
              },
              error: function (ex) {
                  var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                  alert("Message: " + r.Message);
                  alert("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
                  alert("ExceptionType: " + r.ExceptionType);
              }
          });
          return false;
      }
```

[Screenshort of Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FC3zH.png)

Comment: this should be the query `"select RIGHT('00000' + cast(ISNULL(MAX(User_Id),0)+1 as varchar(5)) + '',6) from secUsers"`

Comment: I think you want to use `SqlQuery` instead of `ExecuteSqlCommand` if you want to return a result set.

Comment: when i use SQLQUERY IT GIVE ME THE RESULT IS THIS "select RIGHT('00000' + cast(ISNULL(MAX(User_Id),0)+1 as varchar(5)) + '',6) from secUsers"

Answer (score 0):

This should be the query `select RIGHT('00000' + cast(ISNULL(MAX(User_Id),0)+1 as varchar(5)) + '',6) from secUsers`, you have to put   a space between `)` and `from`

and you need to use the method [SqlQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0), not the `ExecuteSqlCommand` . `SqlQuery` returns you the result set. `ExecuteSqlCommand` 
returns the result by the database after executing the command.

Comment: You don't need a space there. The sql parser can handle it.

Comment: @viveknuna you are right but i already check SQLQUERY it give me "select RIGHT('00000' + cast(ISNULL(MAX(User_Id),0)+1 as varchar(5)) + '',6) from secUsers" not return value.